# GWT - Is manually removing the native events handlers necessary on detach/unload?

Tags: java, memory-management, gwt

If widgets are added to panels (DOM) and also native handlers (ClickHanlder or MouseDownHandler for example), without keeping a reference to them, is there a need for manually removing the handler from the registration on detach/unload to avoid memory leaks or bad memory management?

Example:

```
//at first, somewhere locally
Button b = new Button("My button");
b.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){...}) // or just (event -> {do stuff here})
globalPanel.add(b); //some generic scope panel

//later that evening...
globalPanel.clear();
//then maybe do other similar stuff, adding widgets and handlers, repeatedly
```

So is there a need to keep the handler registration and remove it on some other onDetach/onUnload call? Because in this case there is no reference held for button "b" or the click handler.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You don't need to remove the handler.**

GWT actually does much more, it uses bitfields to sink DOM event to fix some old browsers problems with cyclic references. Although nowadays it's useless, all browsers handle cyclic references correctly. More info in this [>10 years old article](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/dom_events_memory_leaks_and_you.html).